# Add menu items in wagtail ModelAdminGroup

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I want to add non `ModelAdmin` items in a `ModelAdminGroup` as for example a `MenuItem`, like this:

```
MenuItem('A title', '/some_url/', icon_name='doc-full-inverse', order=1)
```

But I could not found any hints neither in Wagtail documentation nor on stackoverflow.

My `ModelAdminGroup` looks like this

```py
class MyModelAdminGroup(ModelAdminGroup):
    menu_label = "Some stuff"
    menu_icon = "fa-suitcase"
    menu_order = 1
    items = (Model1Admin, Model2Admin)
```

I try to do this:

```py
class MyModelAdminGroup(ModelAdminGroup):
    menu_label = "Some stuff"
    menu_icon = "fa-suitcase"
    menu_order = 1
    items = (Model1Admin, Model2Admin, MenuItem('A title', '/some_url/', icon_name='doc-full-inverse', order=1))
```

And some other idiotic stuff

But all I try crashed ...

I finally found an easy solution. I just write it bellow just in case it could help the community other people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came with a trivial solution: just extending my custom `ModelAdminGroup` class and writing a specific `get_submenu_items` method:

```py
class MyModelAdminGroup(ModelAdminGroup):
    menu_label = "Some stuff"
    menu_icon = "fa-suitcase"
    menu_order = 1
    items = (Model1Admin, Model2Admin)

    def get_submenu_items(self):
        menu_items = super().get_submenu_items()
        menu_items.append(MenuItem('A title', '/some_url/', icon_name='doc-full-inverse', order=1))
        return menu_items
```